# os.walk only counting top level subfolders instead of the entire tree

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to better understand os.walk to do various things for this mini program. The program is suppose to count the size of the subdirectories in MB, then within that initial subdirectory count how many folder and files it has within it.

Such as:

```
main folder
|
|--folder 1
|  |- subfolder 1
|   |- subsubfolder 1
|---  subfolder 2
|--folder 2
|   |- subfolder 1
```

and so on

On the way of researching and looking up on how best to do this I've stumbled upon this code snippet

```
import os
def get_size(source, total_size):
    total_size_in = total_size
    for item in os.listdir(source):
        itempath = os.path.join(source, item)
        if os.path.isfile(itempath):
            total_size += os.path.getsize(itempath)
        elif os.path.isdir(itempath):
            total_size += get_size(itempath, total_size)
    return total_size - total_size_in


def walk_recursive(directory, level):
    for d in next(os.walk(directory))[1]:
        itempath = os.path.join(directory, d)
        size = get_size(itempath, total_size=0)
        if level == 0:
            path = d
        else:
            path = '\\' + d
        print('    '*level +
              '{:6.2f}'.format(float(size) / 1048576) + ' MB  ' + path)
        path = os.listdir(directory)[0]
        if path:
            for f in [path]:
                itempath2 = os.path.join(directory, f)
                if os.path.isdir(itempath2):
  #orginal code    walk_recursive(itempath, level + 1)
                   print(len(next(os.walk(itempath, level + 1))[1])) #code i added in
                

directory = r"<put_your_dir_path_here>"
walk_recursive(directory, level=0)
```

I've been breaking this apart, researching parts of the code for seperate functions and what they do, (I believe I mostly understand everything it does, the get_size function still kinda confuses me). It has been a big help in understanding how os.walk works and iterations.

The `print(len(next(os.walk(itempath, level + 1))[1]))` does work to get me the subfolder count, but it only gets me the top level of the subfolder count, and it doesn't get the subsubfolders. How could I get it to work to search trough the subsubfolders and tally up those to the overall subfolder count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally when using `walk` you would want to do so with a for loop. If you look at the yield for walk `yield top, dirs, nondirs`

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
```

Counting the number of dirs and files at each level would just be:

```
len(dirs) + len(files)
```

You can also loop through the sub-directories to calculate size as well:

```
for d in dirs:
    size = get_size(os.path.join(root, d))
```

I'd encourage you too look at the source for walk, it's not very big and most of it you should be able to grasp pretty readily. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/96f65835f8f66d058b444e0b4e436af45e2902f7/Lib/os.py#L344

Comment: Thanks a lot! Following what you said did help me get it to start to print out each folder or file! Looking over the source file did help, and I'll be studying it more. Though one problem I couldn't figure out is how to get the total sum of the files or folders. The github shows a couple examples with sum, but I couldn't get an answer out from them. I know you can't get the sum by iterating ints, is there a way to get around this and display the total folders and files?